# OAuth in Node.js Etsy

Tags: php, node.js, oauth

I am developing an etsy application on Node.js and I need to use OAuth to access app user's accounts. 
Etsy provides the following PHP example:

```
$base_uri = 'https://openapi.etsy.com';
$api_key = 'YOURAPIKEY';
$secret = 'YOURSECRET';
$oauth = new OAuth($api_key, $secret);
$req_token = $oauth->getRequestToken($base_uri . '/v2/oauth/request_token?scope=', 'oob', "GET");
$login_url = $req_token['login_url'];
print "Please log in and allow access: $login_url \n\n";
$verifier = readline("Please enter verifier: ");
$verifier = trim($verifier);
$oauth->setToken($req_token['oauth_token'], $req_token['oauth_token_secret']);
$acc_token = $oauth->getAccessToken("https://openapi.etsy.com/v2/oauth/access_token", null, $verifier, "GET");
$oauth_token = $acc_token['oauth_token'];
$oauth_token_secret = $acc_token['oauth_token_secret'];
$oauth->setToken($oauth_token, $oauth_token_secret);
print "Token: $oauth_token \n\n";
print "Secret: $oauth_token_secret \n\n";
```

Must of this seems pretty straght forward. Obvously,the first few lines would become:

```
const base_uri = 'https://openapi.etsy.com';
var api_key = 'YOURAPIKEY';
var secret = 'YOURSECRET'
```

So how would I convert the rest into javascript/Node.js? Is there an OAuth package for Node?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, multiple libraries exist in the Node ecosystem: https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=oauth2